# Wordpress Group By Problem

Tags: loop, groupby

i have a custom post type called "events". in this post type, i have a metabox with the date of the event. saved as timestamp. my problem is, i want a whole year with every month. 
current only the month is displayed where an event is - but i want every month of a year ...

so this is my loop

```
query_posts( 
    array( 
        'paged' => $paged ,
        'post_type' => array (
            'events_national', 
            'events_international' ),
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'meta_key' => '_kk_datum_anfang',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    )
);
```

this is the output:

```
<?
 if ($event_monat !== $event_monat_check) {
    echo "<h2 class='monat'>" . $event_monat . "</h2>";
 }
 $event_monat = $event_monat;
?>    

<li><?php echo $event; ?>----<b><?php the_title(); ?></b> - <?php echo strftime( "%d.%m.%Y", $event_anfang_datum ); ?>
- <?php echo $event_kategorie[0]->name; ?> - <?php echo $event_veranstaltungsort; ?> -
<?php echo $event_prioritaet [0]->name; ?> 
</li>
```

so current is month with event ... i want every month ...

can someone help me ? ... must i created two more taxonimies with every month and a year ?

Comment: Please use upper- and lowercase chararcters and try to write in full sentences with punctuation, etc. At least this is no chat.

Comment: 1) Please don't use `query_posts`. 2) I don't see anything in the query that would limit the returns to one particular month. 3) Try to explain the problem in more detail and include more code. I get the feeling that information is missing.